is it possible to use the azure blob storage as a postgresql database server in a django project?
I want to apply the PostgreSQL database in a azure blob storage In my Django Project. Because azure blob storage is cheaper than the SQL database on azure.
Is technically possible ?

Have you tried any approach so far? @Nayem Jaman Tusher

It is not theoretically viable to use Azure Blob Storage as a straight replacement for a relational database such as PostgreSQL in a Django project. Blob storage is intended to store unstructured data such as photos, videos, documents, and other files, rather than structured relational data, which PostgreSQL manages.

many many Thanks.
